# unknown error titanium json using webapp development

Tags: javascript, json, titanium

I'm getting an unknown error where the loginConnect.onload should run.

I was following an older tutorial located at http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/titanium-user-authentication-part-1--mobile-3728

Any help would be appreciated! thank you!

```
  var loginConnect = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();


    function gridWindow(e){
    if($.username.value != ""&&$.password.value != ""){

loginConnect.open("POST","http://localhost:80/grid/indexgrid.php");

var params = {
        username: $.username.value,
        password: Ti.Utils.md5HexDigest($.password.value)
   };
    loginConnect.send(params);

        }   else{
alert('All fields are required');
 }
 };

loginConnect.onload = function()
{
var json = this.responseText;
var response = JSON.parse(json);
if (response.logged == true)
{
    alert("Welcome back");

} else {
    alert('not working');
      }
  };

   $.index.open();
```

Comment: What is the exact error text? Any starting idea of what is happening?

Comment: Running the Javascript code in the MVC model of titanium studio on a browser.  The error in Firefox is an "unknown error" it seems to take place at the loginconnect.Onload portion everything above the works fine.  I looked into the JSON being encoded or parsed improperly but that seems to be working.

Comment: In chrome the error is "Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected end of Input at index.html/"

Comment: Removing the JSON.parse from  var response = JSON.parse(json);

now.....
 var response = json;

seems to be working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
loginConnect.send(JSON.stringify(params));
```

Comment: I tried this just now.  Same result as before. I'm starting to think it might be a ) or } that is missing.

Comment: This got me along the right lines - looks like not parsing the return was needed.